# RestKit RKObjectMapping mapping a simple root array

Tags: swift, restkit, rkobjectmapping

For a simple object response

```
{"api_key": "cool api key"}
```

I use `RKObjectMapping` like this:

```
class APIRegisterResult: NSObject {
    var api_key: String = ""
}


let registerMapping : RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: APIRegisterResult.self)
registerMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(["api_key"])

objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: registerMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.POST, pathPattern:"register", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 200)))
```

How to use it for a simple array reponse?

```
[{"id:"cool id"},{"id":"cooler id"}]
```

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: Did you sovle this eventually? I've got the same question.

Comment: yeah, just use mappingObject.array() and map it like a simple object